# Get pivot field value for many to many relation in Laravel 5 app

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to get field value from pivot on many to many relationship in my Laravel 5.4 application.

I have following tables in my MySQL database:

```
products
 + id
 + name
 + ...


nutrients
 + id
 + name
 + ...

products_nutrients
 + product_id
 + nutrient_id
 + value
```

***products*** and ***nutrients*** tables have its equivalent Eloquent model (***Product*** and ***Nutrient***) with properly working many to many relationship between them.

I need to list all products with values of certain nutrients. I know id of wanted nutrients, so I can set it in query.
Result should look like collection/array following  of element:

```
- product name
- value of nutrient id 1 for product
- value of nutrient id 2 for product
- value of nutrient id 3 for product
```

How can I figure it out using Eloquent query builder or in the worst case in raw SQL query? I want to avoid solution with foreach loop.

I am trying to achieve it but without success. I would be glad of any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by raw SQL query:

```
SELECT product.name, protein.value as protein, fats.value as fats, carbo.value as carbo
FROM products product
LEFT JOIN products_nutrients protein ON (product.id = protein.products_id AND protein.nutrients_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN products_nutrients fats ON (product.id = fats.products_id AND fats.nutrients_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN products_nutrients carbo ON (product.id = carbo.products_id AND carbo.nutrients_id = 3)
```

Here is also Eloquent way to achieve the same as above:

```
$query = DB::table('products')
    ->join('products_nutrients as protein', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'protein.products_id');
        $join->where('protein.nutrients_id', '=', 1);
    })
    ->join('products_nutrients as fats', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'fats.products_id');
        $join->where('fats.nutrients_id', '=', 2);
    })
    ->join('products_nutrients as carbo', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'carbo.products_id');
        $join->where('carbo.nutrients_id', '=', 3);
    })
    ->select('name', 'protein.value as protein', 'fats.value as fats', 'carbo.value as carbo');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `->pivot` attribute. From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> As you have already learned, working with many-to-many relations requires the presence of an intermediate table. Eloquent provides some very helpful ways of interacting with this table. For example, let's assume our User object has many Role objects that it is related to. After accessing this relationship, we may access the intermediate table using the pivot attribute on the models:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I know this way to achieve it but it is not optimal. I would like to resolve it by using one query, not foreach loop.

Comment: @zyx4sdk I'm sure you already have `Product` instance in this case since you're getting a product name, so this code will create just one query. `foreach` loop will not create N+1 queries in this code.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin This will create one query ONLY if you specified to load every children of the product. To do that, you can use ```->load('nutrients')```. See more https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @Treast I've tried this exact code and it created one query to get a User object and another one query was executed by the foreach part.

Comment: My goal is to handle it in just sql query (best in Laravel query builder) because I am using this in DataTables service, where this query is additionally handled by current DataTables conditions.

Comment: @zyx4sdk but you've asked for an Eloquent solution "How can I figure it out using Eloquent query builder or in the worst case in raw SQL query?"

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes - beacuse it is just what I need to handle it then in my DataTable service. I told about DataTables to tell you that I need getting this data in query (foreach solution isn't good there). When I will have properly query getting these data DataTables will handle it properly.
If you are more interested about why I need query way to get data: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service

Comment: Thank Youu! Note to anyone else, make sure to also add ->withPivot(['col', 'col2',...]); to end of your belongsToMany() statement.